# Why x = 7 < 5 ; print(x) gives false in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-operations

```
x = 7 < 5
print(x)
```

> When I am printing x why its showing false although it should be true?

```
x = 7 > 5 
print(x)
```

> This is True

Comment: The expression `7 < 5` is false... why do you think it should be true?

Comment: `x < y` means  "x is less than y". "7 is less than 5" is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up the direction of the inequality operators.

When Python sees `x = 7 < 5`, it finds the truth value of the inequality `7 < 5` and assigns it to `x`. 7**is not** less than 5, so the statement `7 < 5` is `False`. So Python says `x = False`.

The reverse is true of `x = 7 > 5`. 7 **is** greater than 5, so `7 > 5` is `True` and `x = True`.

Remember the alligator method: < and > are like a hungry alligator looking for the most food it can eat, so it will point toward the larger value and away from the smaller.

Comment: Got it , This means x = 5 < 7 will print True. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

It should not be true. 7 is not less than 5, and therefore evaluates to False.